# Сравнить данные в одном столбце

Tags: sql, oracle

Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Пример, столбец таблицы:

- -1
- 0
- 1
- -2
- 4
- 1
- -1
- 3
- ...

Нужно посчитать количество 1 в столбце а после, это значение поделить на сумму столбца не учитывая посчитанные 1 (единицы).

Есть мысли как это сделать 2-мя процедурами, а вот как это сделать в одной?

Comment: `select count(case when col = 1 then 1 end) / sum(case when col != 1 then col else 0 end) from table_name` ?

Comment: Да, правильно!
Я как то не подумал кейс закинуть в другую функцию.
Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select count(case when col = 1 then 1 end) / sum(case when col != 1 then col else 0 end) as result
from table_name;
```